# Has anyone successfully utilized IPPS for socket printing in Python or JS?

Tags: sockets, security, printing

I can successfully socket print what I need with both via IPP, but can find no documentation on it being done securely via IPPS.  Does anyone know if it's even possible?

```
Code:
```

```
    var ipp = require("ipp");
    var printer = ipp.Printer("https://printer.example.com:443/ipp/print");

    var msg = {
      "operation-attributes-tag": {
        "requesting-user-name": "Bill Raley",
        "document-format": "image/pwg-raster",
        "requested-attributes": ["printer-description", "job-template", 
    "media-col-database"]
      }
    };

    printer.execute("Get-Printer-Attributes", msg, function(err, res) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(res);
    });

    Error:
    { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8) code: 
    'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

Comment: Please post some code; tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I think this is entirely dependent on the printer. An IPPS request is just an HTTPS request with the post data encoded in a particular way. JS can certainly send HTTPS requests. I presume Python can. Do you have the correct certificate on the client?

Comment: I have the certificate, and have had the vendor validate it is correct.